# Disputed "Not an Answer" flag

Tags: discussion, flagging

So it's about [DeepCrawl’s answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/97046/) to the question [How can I make an AngularJS ecommerce website locally crawlable?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/93719/how-can-i-make-an-angularjs-ecommerce-website-locally-crawlable).

It didn't answer the question, I flagged that answer as a "Not an Answer", and flag gets disputed.

Link to the "helpful" site: https://www.deepcrawl.com/knowledge/best-practice/angular-js-and-seo/

Why?

Answer (score 6):

That answer is from an official representative from a product mentioned in the question.   The answer is more than just a link.    It says the product supports the desired feature in some circumstances.   The link looks relevant and non-spammy to me.

I'm not the one who declined the flag, but I would agree with the flag reviewer that determined that the answer is in fact an answer.

The answer doesn't address the portion of the question about how to change the site to make it crawlable.   Adding a comment to the answer pointing that out could be a good way to get an edit with additional info.   However, answers don't *have* to be comprehensive to be useful.

Declined flags don't count against you in any way.   They are only a feedback mechanism to you from the moderators about how your flags were handled and whether that particular flag was useful for moderators to see.

Comment: Yeah, I know that answers don't need to be comprehensive, just, I thought that this is little bit spammy, and the structure of answer looked like no answer to me. Thanks for clarification Stephen.

Comment: That question has received responses from representatives from both crawlers mentioned in the question.   There is the possibility that other people associated with crawlers try to post and recommend that their crawler has the needed feature.   I just edited the question to focus more on the changing the site aspect rather than the asking for crawler recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. :)